# how to resize image to match parent in android

Tags: android

I have a ImageView with width as MatchParent and height as 200DP. I want the image to fill this image view regardless the actual size of image, Anyhow. I tried a bit line of code:

```
Display dis= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int dpi=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
int height=200*dpi/160

if(profileOrCover.equalsIgnoreCase("cover"))
    img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, dis.getWidth()*dpi/160, height, false));
```

I Need help.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

`img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);` to apply scaleType.

Comment: The image was filled in the ImageView But if the image is very long then what happens that the image is filled in the ImageView But more than half of the image from bottom side in not shown..How to resolve this..??

Answer (score 1):

> Declare this property of Imageview in xml

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

if u add this code in your imageview tag in xml file it is enough to get your requirement

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
```